# How to use maven lifecycle inside docker

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, visual-studio-code

First, I don't want to use devcontainers since it is slow.(at least for me)

I got a working docker-compose/Dockerfile for spring boot but I am unable to use vscode's maven to execute it inside container.

Current status:

1. Run maven's clean
2. in window's host's terminal, automatically runs: `"c:\...\project\mvnw.cmd" clean -f "c:\...\project\pom.mxl"`.

I don't want the current state since

1. In my windows PC, I am using old version of JAVA
2. I want to use the specific JAVA version inside container (what if I have another project that uses newer or older version of JAVA)

What I would like is either of the following:

1. Click maven's clean runs: `docker exec <container> /../project/mvnw clean`
2. Somehow change the java_home target of vscode to use docker container/image (maybe via settings.json, idk)

Below are the relevant files and settings:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  app:
    container_name: springbootapp-app
    # restart: always
    build: ./docker
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "5005:5005" # for debugger in container
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./project:/var/www/project:cached
      - ./docker/$ENTRY_POINT:/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh:cached
      - ./.m2:/root/.m2
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim-buster

# WORKDIR
WORKDIR /var/www/project

#Start application
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["bash"]
```

entrypoint

```
#!/bin/sh
# You can set here anything you need before starting the spring boot application

clear
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005
./mvnw spring-boot:run # run spring boot on load
```

With this setup, containers are up, spring-boot is executed indefinitely, can create crud in windows project and is directly mounted to container, etc. But when I want to use the maven lifecycle (clean, test) it always targets the `pom` file in the Windows host instead of container pom. Is there any `settings.json` option that I can update so that vscode->maven will always target/execute in container?

Note: I feel that I also need to change the `JAVA_HOME` to target the java inside the docker container but not important as of now.

Comment: You mean _test_ containers? They run a docker container too. How do they slow down the build?

Comment: I mean **Dev Containers: Add Dev Container Configuration Files** when I do `ctrl + shift + p`  I feel it is slow in general. Also need to reinstall vscode plugins inside docker container.

Comment: What do you mean by 'vscode->maven will always target/execute in container?' Did you expect `VSCode->maven` to `docker exec` into your container?

Comment: @crizzis. Yes hopefully.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)